# Bulk upload data to GAE not working. Always get appcfg.py: error: no such option: -?

Tags: google-app-engine, appcfg

I have done this before but now I don't seem to be able to get this working anymore. I need to upload a csv file to my GAE app. Trying to use app cfg.py upload_data like so:

```
appcfg.py upload_data -—config_file=config.yml -—url=http://[my-app-id].appspot.com/remote_api -—filename=file.csv -—kind=RideDetails
```

I keep getting this error:
"appcfg.py: error: no such option: -?"

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the type of '-' you have: the ones for your options in the code block are em-dashes, not '-'.

Comment: Wow. Amazing. That was it. If you post your comment as an answer then I'll tap to accept it.